# Link_to with anchor doesn't go to the specific id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

In the footer of my website, I have a menu, where I create links to other pages. A part of that menu looks like this:

```
<ul class="footer-menu-content">
  <li><%= link_to 'All games', games_path %></li>
  <% Category.all.each do |category| %>
    <li><%= link_to category.name, games_path(anchor: category.name.downcase.parameterize) %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

And on the page, where `games_path` leads, the code is as follows:

```
<% @categories.each_with_index do |category, index| %>
    <div id="<%= category.name.downcase.parameterize %>" class="row game-category">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <p class="all-games-category-title"><span style="background: url(<%= category.cat_image %>) no-repeat">
          </span><%= category.name %>
        </p>
     </div>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

The `link_to` generates HTML, for example: `<a href="/games#blackjack">Blackjack</a>`, and when I click the link, it redirects me to `http://localhost:3000/games#blackjack`, but it doesn't go to the specific element with id `blackjack`. If I copy the url and paste it into the browser, everything works fine. So, what can be wrong, and what can be done, to make the click work? Thanks.

Comment: anchors != div.id!

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Are you by any chance using Turbolinks? Does disabling it on those links make it work?

Comment: anchors are NOT ids of divs. You will need to add a names `<a>` in your target page. (https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/1995-archive/Elements/A.html)

Comment: Yes, it seems to be turbolinks. Disabling turbolinks solves the issue. But is there any solution to make the anchors work with turbolinks? Adding `data: { no_turbolink: true }` to the `link_to` helper doesn't work.

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using?

Comment: `data: { turbolinks: false }` solves the issue, thanks!

Comment: If you're on Rails 5, then try `data: { turbolinks: false }`